# Change content on Onchange event in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I just started working in Javascript. I have implemented onchange event in JS through code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function fun()
    {
        var x=document.getElementById("price1");
        document.forms['forms1'].price.value=x.value*2;
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="forms1">
    Enter Price: <input type="text" id="price1" onchange="fun()">   
    value is: <input name="price" type="text" >
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But problem is that I get output like

> value is: |***_*_**|

but I want it like a paragraph without `input tag` (i.e not in a box). I want it to be changed like a text. e.g `value is: 20` not `value is:|___20___|`. Any help?

Comment: Either set the `innerHTML` of a `p` tag or remove the borders from your input with CSS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mdUHU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to style the input box

```
<input name="price" type="text" class="text" disabled />
```

and

```
.text{
    border:0;
    background-color:transparent;
    color:black;
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ttpFa/

---

the other would be to use a `span` to hold the price instead of an `input` element.

```
<form name="forms1">
    Enter Price: <input type="text" id="price1" onchange="fun()"/>   
    value is: <span id="price"></span>
</form>
```

and

```
function fun()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("price1");
    document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=x.value*2;
}
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/ttpFa/1/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/utipob/1/

Use span:

value is: `<span id="price"></span>`

and change JS to:

```
    function fun()
    {
        var x=document.getElementById("price1").value;
        document.getElementById('price').innerHTML=x*2;    
    }
```